# Application terminated with Segmentation fault error

Tags: ruby

I am currently using ruby 1.9.3 on windows machine and I have created a tool that extracts records from oracle database and does some processing on those records.

I am using dbi for the connection. In case of some tables it works fine but in some cases it just fails with the following error message:

```
   C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbd-odbc
    -0.2.5/lib/dbd/odbc/statement.rb:41: [BUG] Segmentation fault
    ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]

    -- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
    c:0013 p:---- s:0079 b:0079 l:000078 d:000078 CFUNC  :fetch
    c:0012 p:0014 s:0076 b:0075 l:000074 d:000074 METHOD C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS
    ~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbd-odbc-0.2.5/lib/dbd/odbc/stateme
    nt.rb:41
    c:0011 p:0093 s:0071 b:0071 l:000070 d:000070 METHOD C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS
    ~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi/handles/statement
    .rb:211
    c:0010 p:0065 s:0066 b:0066 l:000065 d:000065 METHOD C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS
    ~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi/handles/statement
    .rb:240
    c:0009 p:0194 s:0062 b:0062 l:000f0c d:00142c BLOCK  C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS
    ~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/src/Oracle/Oracle_Data_Extractor_3.0.rb:349
    c:0008 p:---- s:0058 b:0058 l:000057 d:000057 FINISH
    c:0007 p:---- s:0056 b:0056 l:000055 d:000055 CFUNC  :each
    c:0006 p:0289 s:0053 b:0053 l:000f0c d:0009dc BLOCK  C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS
    ~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/src/Oracle/Oracle_Data_Extractor_3.0.rb:337
    c:0005 p:---- s:0047 b:0047 l:000046 d:000046 FINISH
    c:0004 p:---- s:0045 b:0045 l:000044 d:000044 CFUNC  :each
    c:0003 p:1373 s:0042 b:0042 l:000f0c d:00267c EVAL   C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS
    ~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/src/Oracle/Oracle_Data_Extractor_3.0.rb:304
    c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
    c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:000f0c d:000f0c TOP

    -- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
    C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/src/Oracle/Oracle_Data_Extractor_
    3.0.rb:304:in `<main>'
    C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/src/Oracle/Oracle_Data_Extractor_
    3.0.rb:304:in `each'
    C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/src/Oracle/Oracle_Data_Extractor_
    3.0.rb:337:in `block in <main>'
    C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/src/Oracle/Oracle_Data_Extractor_
    3.0.rb:337:in `each'
    C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/src/Oracle/Oracle_Data_Extractor_
    3.0.rb:349:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbi-0.4.
    5/lib/dbi/handles/statement.rb:240:in `each'
    C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbi-0.4.
    5/lib/dbi/handles/statement.rb:211:in `fetch'
    C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbd-odbc
    -0.2.5/lib/dbd/odbc/statement.rb:41:in `fetch'
    C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbd-odbc
    -0.2.5/lib/dbd/odbc/statement.rb:41:in `fetch'

    -- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll(KiFastSystemCallRet+0x0) [0x7c82845c]
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll(WaitForSingleObject+0x12) [0x77e61c8d]
    C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\1\ocr21.tmp\bin\msvcrt-ruby191.dll(rb_vm_bugr
    eport+0xf9) [0x62e5c61d]
    C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\1\ocr21.tmp\bin\msvcrt-ruby191.dll(rb_name_er
    r_mesg_new+0x17a) [0x62d3a6fa]
    C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\1\ocr21.tmp\bin\msvcrt-ruby191.dll(rb_bug+0x2
    f) [0x62d3b45b]
    C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\1\ocr21.tmp\bin\msvcrt-ruby191.dll(rb_check_s
    afe_str+0x1a4) [0x62dee1a0]
     [0x004011e6]
    C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\BIN\MSVCR71.dll(_unDNameEx+0x764) [0x7c35f0c3]

    -- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

    * Loaded script: C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/src/Oracle/Oracl
    e_Data_Extractor_3.0.rb

    * Loaded features:

        0 enumerator.so
        1 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32
    /enc/encdb.so
        2 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32
    /enc/iso_8859_1.so
        3 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32
    /enc/trans/transdb.so
        4 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/ru
    bygems/defaults.rb
        5 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32
    /rbconfig.rb
        6 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/ru
    bygems/deprecate.rb
        7 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/ru
    bygems/exceptions.rb
        8 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/ru
    bygems/defaults/operating_system.rb
        9 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/ru
    bygems/custom_require.rb
       10 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/ru
    bygems.rb
       11 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/ru
    bygems/version.rb
       12 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/ru
    bygems/requirement.rb
       13 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/ru
    bygems/platform.rb
       14 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/ru
    bygems/specification.rb
       15 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/ru
    bygems/path_support.rb
       16 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/ru
    bygems/dependency.rb
       17 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/de
    precated-2.0.1/lib/deprecated.rb
       18 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/1.9.1/delegate.rb
       19 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/db
    i-0.4.5/lib/dbi/row.rb
       20 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/db
    i-0.4.5/lib/dbi/utils/date.rb
       21 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/db
    i-0.4.5/lib/dbi/utils/time.rb
       22 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/db
    i-0.4.5/lib/dbi/utils/timestamp.rb
       23 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/db
    i-0.4.5/lib/dbi/utils/xmlformatter.rb
       24 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/db
    i-0.4.5/lib/dbi/utils/tableformatter.rb
       25 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/db
    i-0.4.5/lib/dbi/utils.rb
       26 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32
    /date_core.so
       27 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date/format.
    rb
       28 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date.rb
       29 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/1.9.1/time.rb
       30 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/db
    i-0.4.5/lib/dbi/sql/preparedstatement.rb
       31 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/db
    i-0.4.5/lib/dbi/sql.rb
       32 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/db
    i-0.4.5/lib/dbi/columninfo.rb
       33 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32
    /bigdecimal.so
       34 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rational.rb
       35 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/db
    i-0.4.5/lib/dbi/types.rb
       36 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/db
    i-0.4.5/lib/dbi/typeutil.rb
       37 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/db
    i-0.4.5/lib/dbi/sql_type_constants.rb
       38 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/db
    i-0.4.5/lib/dbi/exceptions.rb
       39 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/db
    i-0.4.5/lib/dbi/binary.rb
       40 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/db
    i-0.4.5/lib/dbi/handles/driver.rb
       41 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/db
    i-0.4.5/lib/dbi/handles/database.rb
       42 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/db
    i-0.4.5/lib/dbi/handles/statement.rb
       43 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/db
    i-0.4.5/lib/dbi/handles.rb
       44 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/db
    i-0.4.5/lib/dbi/base_classes/driver.rb
       45 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/db
    i-0.4.5/lib/dbi/base_classes/database.rb
       46 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/db
    i-0.4.5/lib/dbi/base_classes/statement.rb
       47 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/db
    i-0.4.5/lib/dbi/base_classes.rb
       48 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/1.9.1/thread.rb
       49 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb
       50 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/db
    i-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb
       51 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ru
    by-odbc-0.99994/lib/odbc.so
       52 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/db
    d-odbc-0.2.5/lib/dbd/odbc/driver.rb
       53 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/db
    d-odbc-0.2.5/lib/dbd/odbc/database.rb
       54 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/db
    d-odbc-0.2.5/lib/dbd/odbc/statement.rb
       55 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/db
    d-odbc-0.2.5/lib/dbd/ODBC.rb
       56 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/1.9.1/getoptlong.r
    b
       57 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/src/User Library/Ruby/credi
    t_card_data.rb
       58 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/src/User Library/Ruby/custo
    m_data.rb
       59 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32
    /enc/utf_16le.so
       60 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32
    /enc/trans/single_byte.so
       61 C:/DOCUME~1/ADMINI~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/1/ocr21.tmp/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32
    /enc/trans/utf_16_32.so

    [NOTE]
    You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
    Bug reports are welcome.
    For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html


    This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
    Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Is the problem with the record content's, that is encoding or some other issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ruby 1.9.3p125 Segfaults under Windows for me too while running nanoc compile command. My best advice is to return to 1.9.3p0 at least for now. I'm trying to raise an issue on the tracking system. Believe me when I say, it's not your fault and there is nothing you can do to fix, just report the issue, that helps a lot to the devs.

Comment: I checked with ruby 1.9.3p0 but the problem is still there.